# 1.21 Gigawatts or 2.21 Gigawatts?

Tags: back-to-the-future, translation, production

In the original "Back to the Future" movie, Doc has his famous "1.21 Gigawatts" scene. But I noticed today that the French version actually is translated "2,21 Gigawatts" (deux virgule vingt et un Gigawatts).

I have two minor arguments for lip syncing : In the French version doc actually pronounce "Gigowatts", so exactitude was not a main worry for the translation team.
Also, the [French wikipedia page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retour_vers_le_futur#cite_note-1) mention that it was a lip syncing problem, but the cited sources make no mention of this. So no definitive proof.

in short : **Was this change made solely for lip syncing ?**

EDIT : To be clear, I am talking about the change of value from 1.21 to 2.21. The change of the dot to the comma is normal in French

Comment: I used "," here because the actor actually pronounce "virgule" in the french version
But the question here is for the change of value, from 1.21 to 2.21 Gigawatts

Comment: Yeah, just to clarify the question as the first two comments hook up at the comma: Given the transcript is correct, he literally says "two comma twenty and one Gigawatts", i.e. 2,21 GW, which is a) the common continental notation (with comma instead of point) and b) a different **value**. The question is *solely* about b). Great find, btw! Looking forward to see the answers.

Comment: Transcript; https://web.archive.org/web/20080324031636/http://pagesperso-orange.fr/viney.nancy/hoverbttf/script1.html

Comment: Per the [(French) BTTF wiki](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Retour_vers_le_futur); "*For lip sync reason, the French DeLorean requires an extra jigowatt to travel through time-- 2.21 gigawatts"*

Comment: Oh man, I completely zoned in on the commas. Totally missed the "2" vs "1". Wow, just wow. Sorry folks.

Comment: Did he pronounce it Gigawatts or Jigawatts?

Comment: In French, it's always pronounced "Jigawatts", so the french version he pronounce Jigowatts (with the o instead of the a that has been discussed elswhere).
In English, i'm not sure of the exact pronunciation

Comment: I'm not sure why anybody would think "deux" is a better lipsync match for "one" than "un" would be.

Comment: I think it was just an error or typo when redubbing the lines, this stuff happens all the time. 

-Warning: TVTropes Link- http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InconsistentDub

Comment: For clarity's sake, I'd pick one decimal presentation for the question and remove the edit note - it's clearly distracting from the point.

Comment: @MrLister: Both _one_ and _deux_ have lip rounding while _un_ has not, so it’s not implausible.

Comment: @chirlu You mean, the whole damn dialogue was translated from English to French, and the lip movements matched perfectly except for that one word?

Comment: @user14111: Not perfectly; but at least in Germany, the dubbers go to great lengths trying to avoid obvious sound/lip mismatches (because those will vex watchers), and rounded vs. unrounded lips is _very_ obvious. In many cases, lip sync is more important to dubbers than sense.

Comment: French use metric Gigawatts.  :P

Comment: I think its just a lip sync issue... Like for starwars IV : In english the princes is in the cell block AA-23 whereas in french its AY-21 3...

Comment: If you hadn't thought of it by now:  asking this on Movies & TV makes it more likely to be seen by someone in “the biz”.

Comment: @can-ned_food Good idea, I'll try that

Comment: @maxpnj:   How the heck is *A I-grecque vingt-et-un trois* a better match for *Ay Ay Twenty-three* than *Ah Ah vingt-trois* ??

Answer (score 1):

Purely for lip-sync.

Deux is closer to the lip form of one (the mouth shape is actually almost identical between deux and the first part of one).

Not sure how they managed to lipsync "virgule" with "dot" tho :))

As for the "Gigowatts" there is a lot of speculation even on the English version. Doc reads it as Jiga-watt, a j sound, which is considered acceptable just like GIF but is a strongly debated subject, mostly since GIGA is a common magnitude factor (unlike GIF which is an acronym created by someone who called it "J"IF himself) that is normally read with a hard G.

Many believe that Back to the future was trying to bring a unit that sounded both big and correct (watt) but without actually being correct so that it remained pure fiction. If that is true, the translation of Gigawatt to Gigowatt in French could be for the same reason (since in french it would be read with as Jigawatt anyway). Would be interesting to see if they also did something like that in other languages; it could confirm the "fake unit" theory that many believe.

Comment: Do you have any source for the lip sync part ? I tend to agree with it, but I still sounds a bit strange

Comment: I've always assumed that Christopher Lloyd mispronounced "gigawatts" because the unit prefix "giga-" got very little use in regular English until consumer electronics started to feature storage in the gigabyte range, and his pronunciation mirrors that of common English words that begin with "g-" (like "gigantic" and "gym"). Yes, other words begin with a hard "g," but I doubt Lloyd or anybody else spent more than 10 seconds mulling the pronunciation of the word. At best, he considered a few cases that came to him immediately, made a decision, and moved on.